# Sending a rapidly changing variable through SPI

Tags: pic, spi, interrupts

I am trying to send the value of a counter running in timer1(32bit) to another chip, ideally through SPI. The timer triggers an interrupt every 1ms to increment the counter. Overall, the variable increments constantly but for some reason the variable goes backwards occasionally.

```
unsigned long t=0;
void timer1ISR(){
   timerFlagBit=0;//clear interrupt flag
   t++;//increment the counter
}
void sendValue(){
   static unsigned long tempT;
   tempT=t; //save the value to a temporary variable
   Spi_Write(tempT>>16); //most sig byte. I only want a three byte value
   Spi_Write(tempT>>8);  
   Spi_Write(tempT); //least sig byte         
}
void main(){
   init();
   startTimer();
   while(1){
      Delay_us(500);
      sendValue();       
   }
}
```

Any advice on how to transmit a rapidly incrementing value?

Here are some examples(I took out repetitive values):
It increments by a step of one from 0 to 20. The next value right after 20 is 99.
It then increments from 99 to 114 by a step of one and then the next value is 95.
After 95 come 96, 97, 98 then 197, 198, 199, 200, 201.
After 201 it jumps back to 182 and starts incrementing from 182 to 196.
After 196, it jumps to 276.

So only at the very beginning it jumps according a pattern if I graph all the values.
It looks like this: [image: screen shot]
After a short while the value stabilizes. I have played with the priority with the timer but nothing has changed.

This is done on a Microchip Pic.

Comment: Can you just transmit a pulse and have the receiving chip count those? What's the setup here?

Comment: It's probably not causing that particular result but one problem is that when you do `tempT=t;` you should probably should declare it as volatile and disable interrupts so there's no chance of the interrupt occuring half-way through reading it. How are you capturing the data for the graph, are you confident that side of things is OK?

Comment: Is it a 32, 16 or 8 bit microcontroller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have a race condition where the interrupt to increment the counter is occuring while the value is being read out.  The solution is to declare the counter variable voltatile and then disable the timer interrupt while you copy the counter value into a temporary register.

Comment: I thought the compiler I use(mikroC) declares all global variables volatile implicitly. Now the problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: @Timtianyang - I don't think **any** sane compiler would define all variables volatile implicitly. That would *massively* limit the available optimization options the compiler has, and probably result in considerably slower code.

Answer (score 2):

Now the race condition has been fixed something else that could be improved with your code is the jitter if that's of any concern for your application. The reason that's likely to occur is that the hardware timer will be locked to the main oscillator frequency whereas functions such as `Delay_us` are normally implemented as a loop of instructions so the timer interrupt will interfere with the accuracy to some degree. At some point the following transition will occur:

- Your 1mS timer interrupt will fire just before before `sendValue()`
- Your 1mS timer interrupt will fire just after `sendValue()` and now you'll have an extra 500uS delay.

If your other code can tolerate sending three SPI bytes from the interrupt (ie you don't have other interrupts or code that would be stalled an unacceptable amount of time) you could simply move the SPI write to within the interrupt:

```
unsigned long tempT = 0;

void timer1ISR(){
   tempT++;
   Spi_Write(tempT>>16);
   Spi_Write(tempT>>8);  
   Spi_Write(tempT);
   timerFlagBit=0;
}
```

But otherwise as the `Delay_us` function will just be sitting in a loop you could also use something like the following code to receive a flag that a new value is available:

```
volatile unsigned long t = 0;
volatile unsigned char new_val = FALSE;

void timer1ISR(){
   t++;
   new_val = TRUE;
   timerFlagBit=0;
}

void sendValue(){
   static unsigned long tempT;
   disable_ints();
   tempT=t;
   enable_ints();
   Spi_Write(tempT>>16);
   Spi_Write(tempT>>8);  
   Spi_Write(tempT);
}

void main() {
   init();
   startTimer();
   while(1){
      if (new_val) {
         sendValue();       
         new_val = FALSE:
      }
   }
}
```

The latter is probably a good way if your main processing loop is doing other stuff. If it's not doing anything else and sending multiple identical values to your SPI port is not a problem you could of course also use a shorter delay or none at all.

Comment: I am thinking about disabling timer too but one thing I'm concerned about is if disabling interrupt could potentially cause delay in firing 1ms interrupt. I'm using dspic33ep at 140mhz and the main loop has some other timer sensitive stuff. Timer1 has been configured with the highest priority.

Comment: I've never used the dspic33ep in particular but disabling the interrupt (for a moment) is different to stopping the timer on every MCU I've used. The timer will still keep counting, so as long as the interrupts are re-enabled before next time it would be fired you won't have a problem.

Comment: Good call, I will try that out.

Comment: Basically, what happens when you disable the interrupt is that a timer event won't be handled with an interrupt immediately.  The timer keeps on running, it's just that the interrupt flag is left set for a few more cycles than normal.  Also, since you're only disabling interrupts for a couple of cycles (only the copy operation, not for the SPI operation) this small delay in processing the interrupt should not cause any problems.  Now, if the ISR is performing time sensitive I/O in addition to incrementing the counter, then you might have a problem.